# Paint an image without removing it on html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, paint, tint

I have a black and white image and i would like to paint it with the color i picked without removing the image. When i start to paint its painting the image borders either.

I would like to still have the image over there and paint just the "background" of a PNG image just like this script: "http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/#demo-sizes"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<!--http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/-->
<script type="text/javascript">


var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

var CanvasLogBook = function() {
    this.index = 0;
    this.logs = [];
    this.logDrawing();
};
CanvasLogBook.prototype.sliceAndPush = function(imageObject) {
    var array;
    if (this.index == this.logs.length-1) {
        this.logs.push(imageObject);
        array = this.logs;
    } else {
        var tempArray = this.logs.slice(0, this.index+1);
        tempArray.push(imageObject);
        array = tempArray;
    }
    if (array.length > 1) {
        this.index++;
    }
    return array;
};
CanvasLogBook.prototype.logDrawing = function() { 
    if (isFirefox) {
        var image = new Image();

        image.src = document.getElementById('can').toDataURL();
        //var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("can");
        //image.src = canvas.toDataURL();

        this.logs = this.sliceAndPush(image);
    } else {
        var imageData = document.getElementById('can').toDataURL();
        this.logs = this.sliceAndPush(imageData);
    }
};
CanvasLogBook.prototype.undo = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, $('#can').width(), $('#can').height());
    if (this.index > 0) {
        this.index--;
        this.showLogAtIndex(this.index);
    }
};
CanvasLogBook.prototype.redo = function() {
    if (this.index < this.logs.length-1) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, $('#can').width(), $('#can').height());
        this.index++;
        this.showLogAtIndex(this.index);
    }
};
CanvasLogBook.prototype.showLogAtIndex = function(index) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, $('#can').width(), $('#can').height());
    if (isFirefox) {
        var image = this.logs[index];
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    } else {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = this.logs[index];
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }
};




$( document ).ready(function() {

    var canvasLogBook = new CanvasLogBook();

    $( "#undo" ).click(function() {
        canvasLogBook.undo();
    });

    $( "#redo" ).click(function() {
        canvasLogBook.redo();
    });


    $( "canvas" ).click(function() {
        canvasLogBook.logDrawing();
    }); 

}); 




var img = document.createElement("img");        // Create a <button> element
img.setAttribute('src','img.png');

var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
    y = 10;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;


   canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);


    ctx.drawImage(img,90, 20); //desenho a img no começo


}

function color(obj) {


    var cor_sombra_selecionado = $('input[name=sombra]:checked').val();
    if ( (cor_sombra_selecionado == '') || (cor_sombra_selecionado =='nenhuma') ){
        ctx.shadowColor = obj.id;
    } else {
        ctx.shadowColor = cor_sombra_selecionado;
    }


    switch (obj.id) {
        case "green":
            x = "green";
            break;
        case "blue":
            x = "blue";
            break;
        case "red":
            x = "red";
            break;
        case "yellow":
            x = "yellow";
            break;
        case "orange":
            x = "orange";
            break;
        case "black":
            x = "black";
            break;
        case "white":
            x = "white";
            break;
    }
    if (x == "white") y = 10;
    else y = 10;

}

function sombra_funcao(cor) {

    var cor_sombra_selecionado = $('input[name=sombra]:checked').val();
    console.log(cor_sombra_selecionado + ' cliquei na cor da sombra');
    if ( (cor_sombra_selecionado == '') || (cor_sombra_selecionado =='nenhuma') ){
        ctx.shadowColor = x;
    } else {
        ctx.shadowColor = cor_sombra_selecionado;
    }



}

function draw() {

    var cor_sombra_selecionado = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    console.log(cor_sombra_selecionado + ' cliquei na cor');
    if ( (cor_sombra_selecionado == '') || (cor_sombra_selecionado =='nenhuma') ){
        ctx.shadowColor = x;
    } else {
        ctx.shadowColor = cor_sombra_selecionado;
    }


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin    = 'round';
    ctx.shadowBlur = 4;


    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();

    console.log("dsa");
    ctx.closePath();
}

function erase() {
    var m = confirm("Want to clear");
    if (m) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
    }
    ctx.drawImage(img,90, 20); //desenho o bg
}

function save() {

    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
}

function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.strokeStyle = x;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            //ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 10, 10,10,10);
            ctx.arc(currX, currY,4,0,2*Math.PI);
            //ctx.arc(currX, currY,2,2,2,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.lineCap = "round";
            ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
            //ctx.stroke();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}

/*$( document ).ready(function() {

(function($) {
  var tool;


  var history = {
    redo_list: [],
    undo_list: [],
    saveState: function(canvas, list, keep_redo) {
      keep_redo = keep_redo || false;
      if(!keep_redo) {
        this.redo_list = [];
      }

      (list || this.undo_list).push(canvas.toDataURL());   
    },
    undo: function(canvas, ctx) {
      this.restoreState(canvas, ctx, this.undo_list, this.redo_list);
    },
    redo: function(canvas, ctx) {
      this.restoreState(canvas, ctx, this.redo_list, this.undo_list);
    },
    restoreState: function(canvas, ctx,  pop, push) {
      if(pop.length) {
        this.saveState(canvas, push, true);
        var restore_state = pop.pop();
        var img = new Element('img', {'src':restore_state});
        img.onload = function() {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 400, 0, 0, 600, 400);  
        }
      }
    }
  };


  });


    $( "#undo" ).click(function() {
    console.log("das");
        history.undo(canvas, ctx);
    });








}); //ready  */



</script>

</head>

<body onload="init()">

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><h3>Desenhar</h3></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

    </div>

    <div class="row">



        <canvas id="can" class='teste' width="500" height="400" style="border:2px solid;float:right"></canvas>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Cores</h3>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:green;"><input type='radio' name='cor' id='green' onclick="color(this)">Verde</label>   </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:blue;"><input type='radio' name='cor' id='blue' onclick="color(this)">Azul</label>   </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:red;"><input type='radio' name='cor' id='red' onclick="color(this)">Vermelho</label>   </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:yellow;"><input type='radio' name='cor' id='yellow' onclick="color(this)">Amarelo</label>   </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:orange;"><input type='radio' name='cor' id='orange' onclick="color(this)">Laranja</label>   </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:white;"><input type='radio' name='cor' id='white' onclick="color(this)">Branco</label>   </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Sombras</h3>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:green;"><input type='radio' name='sombra' value='green' onclick="sombra_funcao('green')">Verde</label>   </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:blue;"><input type='radio' name='sombra' value='blue' onclick="sombra_funcao('blue')">Azul</label>   </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:red;"><input type='radio' name='sombra' value='red' onclick="sombra_funcao('red')">Vermelho</label>   </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:yellow;"><input type='radio' name='sombra' value='yellow' onclick="sombra_funcao('yellow')">Amarelo</label>   </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:orange;"><input type='radio' name='sombra' value='orange' onclick="sombra_funcao('orange')">Laranja</label>   </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> <label style="background:white;"><input type='radio' name='sombra' value='nenhuma' onclick="sombra_funcao('nenhuma')" checked>Nenhuma</label>   </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img id="canvasimg" style="position:relative;float:left;border:1px solid #000" style="display:none;">
            <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="">
            <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="">
            <span class="controller" id="undo">desfazer </span>  
            <span class="controller" id="redo">redo</span>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

A very different solution comes to mind now that canvas has come to stage two: more blending modes, which simplifies the whole process:

- Draw the image, make sure background is white, lines black ("dah" perhaps, but important)
- Change composite (blending) mode to `multiply` - note: does not work yet in IE (incl. v.11).
- Draw your heart out on top of it; create master pieces such as this:

[image: Weee]
<sup>(uh!... a rave-duck)</sup>

This mode will also act more like real paper and markers, ie. subtractive light when blending the colors together.

Here you don't need to worry about alpha channel/transparency as it uses only *blending* mode (no composition but the regular source-over, takes place).

You can further adjust blending ratio by adjusting the global alpha (note also that you will get those overlaps on the line connections - not covered in this answer, but **[one possible solution here (overlap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072686/drawing-on-canvas-with-opacity-dots-in-line-javascript/29073539#29073539)**, and for **[recording points here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050014/html-canvas-art-generate-coordinates-data-from-sketch/21055494#21055494)**).

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.75;   // example, set/adjust before drawing
```

## Demo

```js
var img = new Image;
img.onload = setup;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL8it.png";

function setup() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        lastPos, isDown = false;

    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  // draw duck        
    ctx.lineCap = "round";                                   // make lines prettier
    ctx.lineWidth = 16;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";               // KEY MODE HERE
    
    canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
        isDown = true;
        lastPos = getPos(e);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + (Math.random() * 360) + ", 100%, 85%)";
    };
    window.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (!isDown) return;
        var pos = getPos(e);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastPos.x, lastPos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.stroke();
        lastPos = pos;
    };
    window.onmouseup = function(e) {isDown = false};
    
    function getPos(e) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {x: e.clientX - rect.left, y: e.clientY - rect.top}
    }
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #000;cursor:crosshair}
```

```html
<canvas width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: it works fine for single color , but when i try to use multiple color , new color is rendered behind the old one , any solution for this issue ? my eraser is not working due to this , thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**Redraw the outline on top whenever the user paints an added color**

This is probably the easiest way of always having the original outline above the painted canvas. If you have a colored background outside the original image then redrawing the original image will eliminate any coloring outside the outline.

**An interesting alternative: Use Compositing to color behind the original outline**

If you want your new colorings to always be behind the original outline, you can set `context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over'` and then all your new colorings will always be drawn behind the existing outline.

Note: This technique works by only coloring new pixels where the new pixel doesn't overlap any existing colored pixel.

So, to use this technique, you must make these changes on your outline image:

- Use an outline that is not already filled with a color. William Malone's nice work uses a duck that is already filled with white.  You would have to remove that interior white color.
- Fill the background outside the outline with a color (not transparent)

I include a modified image of William Malone's duck outline that's properly set up to use compositing to always "draw within the lines". Although you can't see it from the image on a white background...

- the background outside the image is colored white
- and the interior of the duck is transparent.

[image]

Here's a quack example, I mean quick example (pun intended!):

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var img=new Image();img.onload=start;img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/duck.png";
function start(){

  cw=canvas.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=img.height;

  ctx.fillStyle='gold';

  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';

  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});


}



function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  isDown=true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // Put your mouseOut stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouseX,mouseY,10,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Important, and hopefully constructive, note with using destination-over - lets say you paint with blue, but then want to use green on top of the blue (still behind the black outline). Now the green will be painted *behind* the blue as well, not on top of it (not that a green duck is better than a blue one). For single colors no problem of course (as in the live example), but something to have in mind for multiple color options (also see the duplicate pointer for a solution to this).

Comment: Yep, multiple colors (and accidental draws spanning 2+ outlined areas) are a problem that needs to be solved. ;-) Perhaps William Malone's original solution using a flood-fill is a winning solution. :-/

Comment: Flood-filling works great but kind of takes away the fun with these type of drawings (imo). :^)

Comment: you guys rocks! Thanks!

Now its ok. But...

About the multiple colors? It just doesnt overlay the first painted color. How can i fix it? How can i deal with the duplicated pointer that Ken wrote?

Comment: Another thing is about the tint. How can i tint all the area of the head of the duck for example?